# How to set a list into DB with sqlite (or achive something similar)

Tags: python, database, list, sqlite

I have a movie that can have any number of genres. I would like to have that list inside a database, but it seems databases cant hold a list in a cell.

Is there any other way to achieve this, so I can have any number of genres connected to a specific movie?

```
class Film:
    def __init__(self, title, genres):
        self.title = title
        self.genres = genres

    def accept_genre(self, genre):
        self.genres.append(genre)

Movie1 = Film("Taxi Driver", ["Drama"])

print(Movie1.genres) #prints ["Drama"]

Movie1.accept_genre("Crime")

print(Movie1.genres) #prints ["Drama", "Crime"]

...
#im thinking something like this but it doesnt work with lists:
def addToDB(title):     
    with conn:         
        c.execute("""UPDATE film SET genres = :genre WHERE title = :title""", 
        {'title': title, 'genres': list,})  addToDB("Taxi Driver")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered storing as a semicolon delimited string?

```
genres_list = ['Comedy','Horror']
# Pass this dictionary into cur.execute:
{'title': title, 'genres': ';'.join(genres_list),}
```

To convert a semicolon delimited string to a list, use the .split method:

```
'Comedy;Horror'.split(';')
# the result is ['Comedy','Horror']
```